# What is difference between render function with destructing syntax and with plain empty parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently coded react and it seemed too verbose to use `this.props`, so I googled some articles and figured out how to do this and try to code it.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    // the usual way
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.value}, {this.props.value2}</div>
    }
}


class MyComponent extends Component {
    // the way of avoding this.props
    render({value, value2}){
        return <div>{value}, {value2}</div>;
    }
}

class ParentComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return <myComponent value={1} value2={2} />
    }
}
```

I do not have a sense of how this is handled internally, so I tried to transpile at https://babeljs.io/repl but it is still difficult to understand what advantages and disadvantages these syntaxes have.

Here is a summary of the questions:

- is it a good idea to use destructuring to reduce the code?
- If not, I wonder why it is not good to use it.

Comment: Hmmm `render({value, value2}){` does this even work? Have you tried it?

Comment: I referenced [here](https://medium.com/@goncalvesjoao/react-es7-decorators-how-to-inject-props-to-your-render-method-27a0a7973106). It needs some more code to make this work.

Comment: OIC author decorates `render` with a decorator that injects props. I'd say this is an overuse of decorators. Someone could easily do the destructuring inside the function itself. Or even use stateless components. BTW you should capitalize class names because code style :) and of course `<myComponent/>` is **not your** component but `React.createElement('myComponent', null)`

Comment: corrected :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no benefits other than making the references to said variables shorter. In other words, less typing and better readability.

For more info, have a look at [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Here are a few other examples, which I found to be more common:

**Desctructuring in stateless functional components:**

```
const MyComponent = ({value, value2}) => (
  <div>{value}, {value2}</div>
);
```

**Destructuring in ReactComponent class:**

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  render(){
    let {value, value2} = this.props;
    return <div>{value}, {value2}</div>;
  }
}
```

For stateful components, you can do the same for your state variables.